# Show area covered by a pincode on Google maps.[Android]

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to implement a code in android to show area covered by a **PINCODE** that is six digit area code on google map as shown in the screenshot attached.[image]

Kindly provide a way how can I accomplish this thing.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [Google Maps Geocoding service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) to locate the area or region that you type in your maps. Geocoding is the process of converting addresses into geographic coordinates, which you can use to place markers or position the map.

Geocoding has a required parameter [`address`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingRequests) that you need to supply in order for it to locate/geocode the address that you type. And this address supports the [`postal_code`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingAddressTypes) that you want to search.

Although this code is in JavaScript, here is the [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple) for the example code and how to use Geocoding.

For the area part that you want to return when searching `postal_code`, I think you can use [`Polygons`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes#polygons).

A `polygon` represents an area enclosed by a closed path (or loop), which is defined by a series of coordinates. Polygon objects are similar to Polyline objects in that they consist of a series of coordinates in an ordered sequence. Polygons are drawn with a stroke and a fill. You can define custom colors, weights, and opacities for the edge of the polygon (the stroke) and custom colors and opacities for the enclosed area (the fill).

For more information about Polygons, Check this [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-arrays) and the above link for documentation.

Also check this sets of link that may give you an idea.

- [How do I show the boundaries of postcodes on google maps?](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-show-the-boundaries-of-postcodes-on-google-maps)
- [How do I highlight any area boundary on Google Maps?](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-highlight-any-area-boundary-on-Google-Maps)
- [Google Maps Highlight a particular area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21016351/google-maps-highlight-a-particular-area)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.but Geocoding doesn't give me set of latlngs of that area.

Comment: but if you need postal_code. I think Geocoding can help you with that.

Comment: I already have postal code and I want to show its area on map.

Comment: @JigarPandya have you found any solution, if yes kindly share here also. i also need same functionality

Answer (score 0):

Currently Google Maps APIs do not expose the boundaries of postal codes areas.

There is corresponding feature request in public issue tracker:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4008

However, it looks like Google didn't set a priority on this task.

**UPDATE**

As @kaskader mentioned I posted a link for Maps JavaScript API feature request. Sorry for confusion.

Please have a look at another answer where you can find a workaround for your question.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43918793/5140781

Comment: Jugar is using the Android SDK, so this is not the FR he is after :)

Comment: Thanks @kaskader, you are right, I updated my answer.