# Highlight whole countries in Google Maps for Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Referring to:

[Highlight whole countries in Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8670859/highlight-whole-countries-in-google-maps)

I'm trying to return the location of selected countrys by the user in the Google Maps Android application.

Something like this but in Android google maps.  Is there a possibility to do this in android?

Is it possible to do this offline?

[image]

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931281/open-local-kml-file-in-google-maps-on-android

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The question about country or other features borders in Google Maps APIs was asked many times, however, unfortunately Google doesn't expose this data publicly.

To highlight the country you should apply your own data as the Google Maps layer. Nice work around was proposed in the following answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40172098/5140781

You can download country borders in GeoJSON format from OSM. After that you can use the Google Maps Android API [Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/) to add [GeoJsonLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/geojson) in your application.

For my example I downloaded the boundaries of Spain in GeoJSON format and loaded the GeoJSON file using GeoJsonLayer.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        LatLng madrid = new LatLng(40.416775,-3.70379);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(madrid, 3F));

        try {
            GeoJsonLayer layer = new GeoJsonLayer(mMap, R.raw.es_geojson, getApplicationContext());

            GeoJsonPolygonStyle style = layer.getDefaultPolygonStyle();
            style.setFillColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            style.setStrokeColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            style.setStrokeWidth(1F);

            layer.addLayerToMap();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e("IOException", ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            Log.e("JSONException", ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

You can download the complete sample project from github, don't forget to change the API key in values/google_maps_api.xml

https://github.com/xomena-so/so41431384

[image]

I hope this helps!

Comment: What is this code, javascript? I looked at github too, but I am lost... is that something you need to compile before publishing?

Comment: This is a Java code. Typically you use Java for Android programming.

Comment: This was really helpful can you let me know, from where I can generate GeoJson file for other countries too.

Comment: how to click on this layer ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically there are two things you are trying to do.

1- Reverse geocode in order to get the position of the clicked country. I used a repo that I found on GitHub in order to do this. Since it was efficient and works offline. --> https://github.com/AReallyGoodName/OfflineReverseGeocode

2- As soon as you get the clicked country, you need to highlight it. as explained by @xomena

You can also check this repo that I made which basically implements this.

https://github.com/moumen7/Map_picker