# Show Area or city boundry in google map using android map api

Tags: android, android-maps, android-maps-utils

I want to show Area or city (search dynamically) boundaries in android app like map.google.com .
I have search lots of things on google.I got this link.[Show city or area outline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31861822/google-maps-how-to-show-city-or-an-area-outline)

as per searching on google,I got KML file that is added on kmllayer and kml layer binds on map.

```
layer = new KmlLayer(googleMap,R.raw.campus, getApplicationContext());
layer.addLayerToMap();
```

But i don't know that how to bind that kml in google map.
As per googling, we have to draw polyline on google map using kml.
but can't finding working solution .

I have another [Reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706484/add-search-area-outline-onto-google-maps-result).But not understand what i have to do in my code.anyone can help me for more detailing about that?

Comment: it may help you -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41431384/highlight-whole-countries-in-google-maps-for-android