# Android Find region data for particular location

Tags: java, android, google-maps, kotlin

I am looking for finding all region data from particular latitude and longitude in google map so that through that region data I want to show polyline border view for all regions in google map. For this, I used place API but unable to find any solution.

For example, if I select Italy as a country than, I want all region data of Italy. With the help of that region data, I want to create border or polyline around the entire Italy country.

[Just Like this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bfy2q.png)

Comment: Google doesn't expose boundaries of geo features in their APIs. You should use alternative data sources, for example, OpenStreetMaps. Have a look at the following answer to figure out how you can implement this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43918793/5140781.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @xomena. Can you tell me how can I get this type of JSON response for a particular country, city or region? Is this static or dynamic? also if it's static than how can I get this type of response. [JSON Response](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xomena-so/so41431384/master/app/src/main/res/raw/us_geojson.json)